# What would happen in real world when queue of MAC layer is full? Drop?

Tags: macos, tcp

Recently I'm doing a network experiment with a simulator. I found when the queue of MAC layer is full, and upper layers (e.g. IP) still forwards packets down to it, this implementation chooses to drop those packets.

What I'm wondering is, in real world implementation, like protocol stack in Linux kernel, if the queue of MAC layer (the buffer of interfaces?) is full, and there are more packets coming from socket, dose it choose to drop them or allocate more memory? and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach should be to flow off. This will push back IP the stack to the socket layer. The `send` or `sendto` APIs will either block or fail and thus flow control is established (a socket should not be able to send faster than the MAC layer can send).

The only time packets should even be dropped is at a de-multiplexing point. This is the case where there are two branches to send to and one of them is blocked. Here you have to drop packets because one may not stop traffic flowing down the one branch because the other branch is blocked.But where there is only one send branch you always flow off.